# regex npp - search string bounded by two strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

In NPP, I need to search/replace from the start of line `"Installed"` all the way down to the `"Rx Coding Error"`, including the trailing numbers (random, any length) and also including the trailing newline character.

I have this regex so far, and it matches everything down to `Rx Coding Error` but cannot see how to add the additional `whitespace + colon + random numbers/length + newline`.

```
\b\s+Installed[\s\S]*?Rx Coding Error\b
```

I am searching for a code block similar to that below:

`EFM Link 1/2/3 on EFM Group 3/2/1 is ENABLED and UP
  Installed                 : YES
  Near end tc sync          : SYNC
  Rx Coding Error           : 595237`

<kbd>[**regex101 fiddle to play with**](https://regex101.com/r/F84BKW/1)</kbd>

Comment: I don't see a clear output. Specify it please.

Comment: Are you expecting this https://regex101.com/r/F84BKW/2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on @SahilGulati's answer:

`^\s+Installed[\s\S]*?Rx Coding Error\s+:\s+\d+\s+`

should do the job, assuming you want to start from the same line of `Installed`

https://regex101.com/r/F84BKW/4

Comment: Glad to know it helped! I hope this does not come off as off-putting but if you'd like to further improve on regex then I could suggest playing with [Regex Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf).

Answer (score 1):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `^\s*Installed[\s\S]*Rx Coding Error.*` It will match string till end of line.

[image]

Comment: Close, but didn't get the trailing newline char - you got further than I did, though, and thanks!